# In-Place upgrade of windows server 2008 r2 standard to Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Where do I find/download DISM utility to perform In-Place upgrade of windows server 2008 r2 standard to enterprise? B/c when I launched the >DISM /Online /Get-CurrentEdition from Administrator Command Prompt window, it said DISM not support. Thanks, Tony

Comment: What was the exact error when running the command?

Answer (score 2):

[DISM is built into 2008 R2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/server_core/archive/2009/10/14/upgrading-windows-server-2008-r2-without-media.aspx).  Verify that you're really running R2 by running Start -> WinVer.

I suspect that you're running 2008 (*not* R2).  If you *are* running R2, double-check your spelling and make sure you didn't typo.